# Detailed age check for users

Tags: javascript, html

/* I want to check for the age of the user, if **18 or above, grant access**. If not proceed to the next block where they are asked **if they are given permission by their parents**. If **(yes || Yes || YES)** grant access. If **(no || No || NO)** deny access. If anything apart from the (yes(s) and no(s)) return **(Wrong input!)**. If (**!yes(s) and !no(s)** "ie, the user cancels,") return **(Try Next time!)**  */

```js
let age = prompt('How old are you?', [18]);
    
function ageChecker(age) {
  if (age >= 18) {
      return 'Access Granted!';
  } 
  else if (!age) {
      return 'Sorry Enter Your Age!';    
  }
  else {
    let confirmation = prompt('Do you have permission from your parents?', ['Yes']); 
    let posResult1 = 'yes';
    let posResult2 = 'Yes';
    let posResult3 = 'YES';


    let negResult1 = 'no';
    let negResult2 = 'No';
    let negResult3 = 'NO';

    if (confirmation) {
        if (posResult1 || posResult2 || posResult3) {
            return 'Access Granted!';               
        }
        else if (negResult1 || negResult2 || negResult3) {
            return 'Access Denied!';
        }
    }
    else {
        return 'Wrong Input Sucker!';
    }

    return confirmation;
  }

 }

 alert( ageChecker(age) );
```

Comment: what is the problem you are having ? i can not see a question here

Comment: what's your question? there is no obvious question

Comment: Please format code..

Comment: From reading the code, I assume the second confirmation is wrong - "Permission from parents", because the OP is checking whether a variable exists or not, instead of checking the input.

Answer (score 0):

The confirmation variable's output should not be compared with the multiple variables, instead of just use the toLowerCase() function

```js
let age = prompt('How old are you?', [18]);

function ageChecker(age) {
    

    if (age >= 18) {
       return 'Access Granted!';
    } 
    else if (!age) {
       return 'Sorry Enter Your Age!';    
    }
    else {
       
        let confirmation = prompt('Do you have permission from your parents?', ['Yes']);
        if ('yes' == confirmation.toLowerCase()) {
            return 'Access Granted!';
        }else if('no' == confirmation.toLowerCase()){
          return 'Access Denied!';
        }else if(!confirmation){
          return 'Try next time';
        }
        else {
            return 'Wrong Input Sucker!';
        }
        
    return confirmation;
    }

   }

   alert( ageChecker(age) );
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to note:

- The result you get back from a prompt is of type **string**, so if you use `age >= 18` it won't be doing a proper comparison. Therefore if you're expecting the user to enter a number, you should convert the result using `parseInt()`.
- The answer to a prompt is stored in the variable you assign the prompt function to, so if you do `const foo = prompt("What is your name");`, the answer will be stored in variable `foo`. Therefore, your if statements need to check the `confirmation` variable.
- If you are not reassigning a variable, make it a habit to use constants (i.e. `const foo = ...` instead of `let foo = ...`).
- Lastly, you can use `toLowerCase()` so you only have to compare the confirmation answers to "yes" and/or "no".

This is a way in which you could write the function instead:

```js
const age = parseInt( prompt('How old are you?', [18]), 10 );

function ageChecker(age) {
  if (!age) {
    return 'Sorry Enter Your Age!';   
  }

  if (age >= 18) {
      return 'Access Granted!';
  } 
  else {
    const confirmation = prompt('Do you have permission from your parents?', ['Yes']);
    
    if (!confirmation) {
      return 'Wrong Input Sucker!';
    }
    
    if (confirmation.toLowerCase() === 'yes') {
      return 'Access Granted!';
    }
    else if (confirmation.toLowerCase() === 'no') {
      return 'Access Denied!';
    }
    
    return 'Wrong Input Sucker!';
  }
 }

alert( ageChecker(age) );
```

Another neat thing you can do when checking the `confirmation` is using a `switch` statement instead of an if statement:

```js
const age = parseInt( prompt('How old are you?', [18]), 10 );

function ageChecker(age) {
  if (!age) {
    return 'Sorry Enter Your Age!';   
  }

  if (age >= 18) {
      return 'Access Granted!';
  } 
  else {
    const confirmation = prompt('Do you have permission from your parents?', ['Yes']);
    
    if (!confirmation) {
      return 'Wrong Input Sucker!';
    }

    switch (confirmation.toLowerCase()) {
      case 'yes':
        return 'Access Granted!';
        
      case 'no':
        return 'Access Denied!';
        
      default:
        return 'Wrong Input Sucker!';
    }
  }
 }

alert( ageChecker(age) );
```

Depending on the use, switch statements can be a much neater way of checking variables than using a bunch of if statements.

Answer (score 0):

I will expand on **Yannik**'s answer with some advice for what I think is best practice in javascript code.

1. Use variables to describe conditions in if statements. It's easier to read for other developers, especially if there are several conditions, like `hasValidAge`, `locatedInEurope`, and `isAdmin`.
2. If the method returns something, return it at the end of the method. That not only makes the code more clear of what it will do, but you are also given a chance to explain - through the variable name - what is returned.
3. Refactor code. Right now, you have ageChecker with a long if statement, which makes it hard to read. But not only that, you also have a method that makes *two* things. It's not only checks age, it also asks for the parent's permission. A method should, in best scenario, only do *one* thing.

I marked the code below to highlight my points.

[EDIT] clarifications based on questions in the comment:

a) The prompt could return `undefined` if the user removes all text. That will make the code crash later on with `confirmation.toLowerCase()`.

```
const confirmation = prompt('Do you have permission from your parents?', ['Yes']) // can return undefined
```

b) I didn't want to sway away too much from your code in my refactor example. If I would have done the refactor properly, I would have used three methods:

```
function ageCheckerAlert() {
  let messageStr = promptAge();
  const invalidAge = messageStr == 'Invalid Age'; 

  if (invalidAge) {
    messageStr = promptParentsPermission();
  }

  alert(messageStr);
}

function promptAge() {
  let messageStr = 'Invalid Age';
  const age = parseInt( prompt('How old are you?', [18]), 10 );

  // if statements that changes messageStr, if either valid age or empty input.

  return messageStr;
}

function promptParentsPermission() {
  // same code as in parentsPermissionChecker() in the snippet below
}
```

By separating the functionality, you get the added benefit of being able to call `promptAge()` or `promptParentsPermission()` alone if you ever would need to do that.

```js
const age = parseInt( prompt('How old are you?', [18]), 10 );

function ageChecker(age) {
  let messageStr;
  const hasValidAge = age >= 18;  // 1

  if (!age) {
    messageStr = 'Sorry Enter Your Age!';   
  }
  else if (hasValidAge) {  // 1
    messageStr = 'Access Granted!';
  } 
  else {
    messageStr = parentsPermissionChecker(); // 3
  }

  return messageStr;  // 2
}

function parentsPermissionChecker() {  // 3
  const confirmation = prompt('Do you have permission from your parents?', ['Yes']) || ''; // added a default string.
  let messageStr = 'Wrong Input Sucker!';
  const typedYes = confirmation.toLowerCase() === 'yes';
  const typedNo = confirmation.toLowerCase() === 'no';

  if (typedYes) {
    messageStr = 'Access Granted!';
  }
  else if (typedNo) {
    messageStr = 'Access Denied!';
  }

  return messageStr;  // 2
}

alert( ageChecker(age) );
```

Comment: Thanks. Quick question. What does the added default string check for? and lastly, in the final statement of the code, (alert), how comes the ageChecker(age) calls both the functions included the one for parentsPermissionChecker()? I you could explain please

Comment: Hi! I edited the post and added longer clarifications. Hope that straightens out the question marks. :)

Comment: Thanks. I understand it now